# Geom_bar_pattern not treating x-axis categories as different

Tags: r, ggplot2

take the following data

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,30,rep=TRUE)))
df <- reshape(data=df, varying=list(1:2), 
        direction="long", 
        times = names(df), 
        timevar="Type",
        v.names="Score")
```

plotted like this:

```
plot <- ggbarplot(df, x = "Type", y = "Score", 
          color = "black", fill = "Type", add = "mean_ci")
```

And I want to add stripes only to X1

```
plot +
         geom_bar_pattern(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", position="dodge",  color="black", width=1,pattern_angle = 45, pattern_density = 0.4,pattern_spacing = 0.025, pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
        scale_pattern_manual(values = c(X1 = "stripe", X2 = "none"))
```

However stripes are added to both x-axis categories (scale_pattern_manual does not work?)

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your error bars with `stat_summary` instead of using `ggpubr::ggbarplot`, then you would get this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

df <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,30,rep=TRUE)))
df <- reshape(data=df, varying=list(1:2), 
              direction="long", 
              times = names(df), 
              timevar="Type",
              v.names="Score")

ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = Score, pattern=Type,
          color = "black", fill = Type)) +
    geom_bar_pattern(stat = "summary", 
                     fun = "mean",
                     position="dodge",  
                     color="black", 
                     width=1, pattern_angle = 45, 
                     pattern_density = 0.4, pattern_spacing = 0.025, 
                     pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c("stripe", "none")) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, geom="errorbar", col="black", width=.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `scale_pattern_manual` will not work in this setting.

To avoid that stripes are added to both cols add `aes(pattern = Type)` to `geom_bar_pattern`.

See [Gallery of ggpattern package](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-geometry.html#geom-bar-pattern-)

```
plot <- ggbarplot(df, x = "Type", y = "Score", 
                  color = "black", fill = "Type", add = "mean_ci")

plot +
  geom_bar_pattern(
    stat = "summary", 
    fun = "mean", 
    position="dodge",  
    color="white", 
    width=0.7,
    pattern_angle = 45, 
    pattern_density = 1,
    pattern_spacing = 0.025, 
    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.8,
    aes(pattern = Type))
```

[image]

Comment: This was helpful but it does not replicate the 2nd column having no pattern.